# Pressure sensitivity Huion 220 GT Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: touchscreen, wacom, xinput, evdev

Touch screen currently working like it is a mouse.

Output of `evtest`:

```
Input driver version is 1.0.1
Input device ID: bus 0x3 vendor 0x256c product 0x6e version 0x111
Input device name: "Tablet Monitor Pen"
Supported events:
  Event type 0 (EV_SYN)
  Event type 1 (EV_KEY)
    Event code 320 (BTN_TOOL_PEN)
    Event code 330 (BTN_TOUCH)
    Event code 331 (BTN_STYLUS)
    Event code 332 (BTN_STYLUS2)
  Event type 3 (EV_ABS)
    Event code 0 (ABS_X)
      Value  24537
      Min        0
      Max    37540
      Resolution     157
    Event code 1 (ABS_Y)
      Value  17217
      Min        0
      Max    21120
      Resolution     157
    Event code 24 (ABS_PRESSURE)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max     2047
  Event type 4 (EV_MSC)
    Event code 4 (MSC_SCAN)
Properties:
```

Which then shows pressure varying between 0 and 2047 as I push the pen into the screen:

```
Event: time 1495431796.081707, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1495431796.085756, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 0 (ABS_X), value 19517
Event: time 1495431796.085756, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 1 (ABS_Y), value 17467
Event: time 1495431796.085756, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 24 (ABS_PRESSURE), value 399
Event: time 1495431796.085756, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1495431796.087752, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value d0042
Event: time 1495431796.087752, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 330 (BTN_TOUCH), value 0
Event: time 1495431796.087752, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 0 (ABS_X), value 19515
Event: time 1495431796.087752, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 1 (ABS_Y), value 17463
Event: time 1495431796.087752, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 24 (ABS_PRESSURE), value 0
Event: time 1495431796.087752, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
```

However, `xinput test "Tablet Monitor Pen"` only shows lines like `motion a[0]=22722 a[1]=17156` with axes that correspond to x and y coordinate on the screen.

**EDIT: Additional info I found**:

When I press the stylus to the screen, the output of `xinput test` registers `button press 1` and when I lift it `button release 1`. I didn't see them before.

Additionally, `xinput list "Tablet Monitor Pen"` outputs

```
Tablet Monitor Pen                          id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
    Reporting 4 classes:
        Class originated from: 11. Type: XIButtonClass
        Buttons supported: 7
        Button labels: "Button Unknown" "Button Unknown" "Button Unknown" "Button Wheel Up" "Button Wheel Down" "Button Horiz Wheel Left" "Button Horiz Wheel Right"
        Button state:
        Class originated from: 11. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 0:
          Label: Abs X
          Range: 0.000000 - 37540.000000
          Resolution: 157000 units/m
          Mode: absolute
          Current value: 22722.000000
        Class originated from: 11. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 1:
          Label: Abs Y
          Range: 0.000000 - 21120.000000
          Resolution: 157000 units/m
          Mode: absolute
          Current value: 17156.000000
        Class originated from: 11. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 2:
          Label: Abs Pressure
          Range: 0.000000 - 2047.000000
          Resolution: 0 units/m
          Mode: absolute
          Current value: 0.000000
```

I noticed `Resolution: 0 units/m` in the above, which seems possibly related? Don't know much about xinput stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1675473 , it works on 17.04 out of the box.